# Using a Dlookup in Access VBA when the field has a single quote

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I've found a lot on this topic but still can't seem to get it to work.  I have the following line of code:

```
If isNull(DLookup("id", my_table, my_field & "='" & temp_value & "'")) Then
```

The problem is a value in `my_field` of `my_table` is "O'Connell" (with a single quote), and I'm not sure how to get Dlookup to find it.  I've tried using:

```
my_field & "=" & chr(34) & temp_value & chr(34)
```

And a host of other multi-quote options, but I just can't seem to get it to work.  Though I can use VBA to modify the temp_value to include or not include the single quote, since the single quote already exists in the table, I need to make sure it matches.  I'm just not sure how to tackle it.

Comment: You can escape the single quote by doubling it up (replacing it with two single quotes).

Comment: Replace("str'ing", "'", "''") will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the suggestions and answers here do work and resolve many issues with quotes in text, my issue ended up being related to the character I was seeing as a single quote not really being a single quote.  For what it's worth, the data I was using was exported from Siebel, and the single quote I was seeing was actually chr(146), where a regular single quote (I say "regular" for lack of a better term) is chr(39).

If having issues with quotes, I found it helpful to examine the chr values of each character in the string.  There may be a better way to do this, but this loop should help:

```
for i=1 to len(a_string)
    debug.print mid(a_string,i,1) & " - " & asc(mid(a_string,i,1)
next i
```

The asc function gives you the chr code for a character, so this loops through the string and shows you each character and its associated chr code in the Immediate window (using debug.print).  This also helps in finding other "hidden" (or non-visible) characters that may exist in a string.

Once discovered, I used the replace function to replace chr(146) with two single quotes (two chr(39)s), as suggested by HansUp, and that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, `my_table` is the name of my table and `my_field` is the name of a field in that table.

```
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim temp_value As String
temp_value = "O'Connell"
' use double instead of single quotes to avoid a '
' problem due to the single quote in the name '
strCriteria  = "my_field = """ & temp_value & """"
Debug.Print strCriteria
If IsNull(DLookup("id", "my_table", strCriteria)) Then
    MsgBox "no id found"
Else
    MsgBox "id found"
End If
```

If you prefer, you can double up the single quotes within the name.  This should work, but make sure you can distinguish between which are double and which are single quotes.

```
strCriteria = "my_field='" & Replace(temp_value, "'", "''") & "'"
```

Comment: @HansUp--this is right, and I appreciate it, but I had actually tried both these options, and neither worked. It turns out that in my table, the value that had an apostrophe actually had one of those curly apostrophes--chr(146)--and not a regular apostrophe--chr(39).  (There are probably more technically precise names for each of those, but I'm just describing how they look.)  In Access, you could not tell a difference when looking at the table--I figured it out when I copied the value to Notepad for testing.  I wanted to note that here in case somebody comes across this in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I encourage you to submit that solution as an answer so it will be more prominent.  And accept that answer instead of mine when the system allows you to do so.  Regards, Hans.

Comment: @rryanp I HATE those apostrophes. You have no idea how much headache I had about a year ago because of one of those things - A paste from Microsoft Word in my code was the culprit. My IDE didn't color-code strings like many do. Oh the horrible, horrible memories.

Comment: @HansUp--okay, I've added an answer and accepted it.  Thanks.  Scotch--definitely frustrating!  It's unfortunate how much time we had to spend just to deal with one little character.  Thanks for your comments.